# Paypal Java creating p12 file - What pem files to include?

Tags: java, paypal, ssl-certificate, pem, p12

In the paypal topic ***[Secure Your HTML Payment Buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/encryptedwebpayments/)*** there is described how to create a     my-prvkey.pem ,     my-pubcert.pem and how to download     paypal_cert_pem.txt .

Now in the part ***Download and Configure EWP software for Manually Created Buttons***:

> *3.Copy your private key, public certificate, **p12** file and the PayPal public certificate to the same folder on your web server where the software is located.*

they are asking for a p12 file.

I found how to create p12 from pem, but I am confused what pem files to include.

Should I include all this files?

```
my-prvkey.pem  
my-pubcert.pem  
paypal_cert_pem.txt
```